# Way to control the activity stack

Tags: android, android-activity

Here's my problem

I am working on a android application that contains the following activities: a register activity, a find friend activity, and a Main Activity.

The expected behavior is like this:

When the user finishes registering, the application will open up the find friend activity. When the user hits the back button at this time, the user should go to the Main Activity. When the user hits back in the Main Activity, the user should quit the app.

I am not sure if overriding the behavior of back-button hit event is the best way to resolve the issue? Maybe there's a good way to manage the activity stack to achieve the same expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify parent activity in the manifest and use taskstackbuilder to create a new backstack for your activity. See [link.](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html).

I believe if you use the addNextIntentWithParentStack(Intent nextIntent) and startActivities() method in the class [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) you should get the result you want.